# Array with all sub-folders and files alphabetically while retaining structure

Tags: php, file

### Overview

We are building a PHP based template engine (original, I know). One of the core features is a template list page where the users can see their user-defined templates and create page objects with them. These files are stored in either a html file or SQL storage system.

We have already got the loading of the files in the template engine down, SQL was a breeze, now we are attempting to load the html files themselves for user parsing and listing.

### The code

We are using the following code to get a list of all the files in the Directory and children, then add them to an array.

```
function get_directory_contents($directory, $hide_index_files = TRUE, $limit_to_html_files = TRUE) {
    $rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
    $files = array(); 
    foreach ($rii as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()){ 
            $files['directories'][] = $file;
        } else {
            if ($hide_index_files) {
                if ($file->getFilename() == "index.html") {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if ($limit_to_html_files) {
                if (substr($file->getFilename(), -5) != ".html") {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            $count_to_filename = strlen($directory . "/");
            $count_from_filename = strlen($file->getFilename());
            $count_from_filename_plus_one = strlen($file->getFilename()) + 1;
            $file_path_full = substr($file->getPathname(), $count_to_filename);
            $remove_name = -1 * abs($count_from_filename_plus_one);
            $file_path = substr($file_path_full, 0, $remove_name);
            if (!$file_path) {
                $file_path = "base_directory";
            }
            $files['files'][] = array("fullpath" => $file_path_full, "justPath" => $file_path, "filename" => $file->getFilename());
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
```

The path is directed to a sub folder in templates called `templates/user-defined` and with the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS` flag enabled, the `files[directories]` field is returning empty - The current code returns the following array:

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fullpath] => hello_world.html
                    [justPath] => base_directory
                    [filename] => hello_world.html
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fullpath] => another_folder/file.html
                    [justPath] => another_folder
                    [filename] => file.html
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [fullpath] => second_folder/alpha_file.html
                    [justPath] => second_folder
                    [filename] => alpha_file.html
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [fullpath] => second_folder/bravo_file.html
                    [justPath] => second_folder
                    [filename] => bravo_file.html
                )
        )
)
```

### Desired Output

We would like to see the list of the array output in alphabetical order with folder structure kept in tact. Currently, the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) we are using sorts the entries by the files last edit time and then we call `asort()` to try and alphabetically sort the items but it doesn't retain the directory schema either.

We would ideally like to support the folders that are empty and list their children under them while we return an array that looks like the following:

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [another_folder] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fullpath] => another_folder/file.html
                            [filename] => file.html
                        )
                )
            [empty_folder] => Array
                (
                )
            [second_folder] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fullpath] => second_folder/file.html
                            [filename] => file.html
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [fullpath] => second_folder/bravo_file.html
                            [filename] => file.html
                        )
                )
            [base_directory] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fullpath] => hello_world.html
                            [filename] => hello_world.html
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

This would allow us to list them like so:

```
/another_folder/
-> file.html

/empty_folder/

/second_folder/
-> alpha_file.html
-> bravo_file.html

/
-> hello_world.html
```

We are using the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator()` and `RecursiveIterator()` functions as they are supposedly faster than a simple scandir and they have a nice Object approach that we prefer.

How can we achieve this while retaining quick loading?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with the `scandir()` function and made a recursive function that you feed the initial path and the length of the path too like the following:

```
$template_path = "/templates/user-defined";
$count_to_filename = strlen(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . $template_path . "/");
$list_of_templates_html = map_directory_contents(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . $template_path, $count_to_filename);


function map_directory_contents($directory, $count, $depth = 0, $base_directory = TRUE, $hide_index_files = TRUE, $limit_to_html_files = TRUE) {
    global $templates;
    $folder_data = array();
    $file_data = array();
    $current_depth = $depth - 1;
    $directory = rtrim($directory, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $files = array_slice(scandir($directory), 2);
    foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
        if (($directory . $file == __FILE__) || (substr($file, 0, 1) === '.')) {
            continue;
        }
        $this_path = str_replace(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '', $directory . $file);
        if (($depth < 1 OR $current_depth > 0) && is_dir($directory . $file)) {
            $folder_data[$file] = array("fullpath" => $this_path, "type" => "folder", "name" => $file, "files" => map_directory_contents($directory . $file, $count, $current_depth, FALSE, $hide_index_files, $limit_to_html_files));
        } else {
            if ($limit_to_html_files) {
                if (substr($file, -5) != ".html") {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if ($hide_index_files) {
                if ($file == "index.html") {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if ($base_directory) {
                if(!isset($file_data["base_directory"]["type"])) {
                    $file_data["base_directory"]["fullpath"] = rtrim($directory, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
                    $file_data["base_directory"]["type"] = "folder";
                    $file_data["base_directory"]["name"] = "/";
                }
                $file_data["base_directory"]["files"][] = array("fullpath" => $this_path, "nonce_id" => $templates->nonce_id, "path" => substr($this_path, $count), "type" => "file", "editable" => (is_writable($this_path) ? TRUE : FALSE), "name" => $file);
            } else {
                $file_data[] = array("fullpath" => $this_path, "nonce_id" => $templates->nonce_id, "path" => substr($this_path, $count), "type" => "file", "editable" => (is_writable($this_path) ? TRUE : FALSE), "name" => $file);
            }
            $templates->nonce_id++;
        }
    }
    !empty($folder_data) ? ksort($folder_data) : false;
    $map_data = array_merge($folder_data, $file_data);
    return $map_data;
}
```

doing this returns the following array:

```
Array
(
    [another_folder] => Array
        (
            [fullpath] => /home/public_html/templates/user-defined/another_folder
            [type] => folder
            [name] => another_folder
            [files] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fullpath] => /home/public_html/templates/user-defined/another_folder/file.html
                            [path] => another_folder/file.html
                            [type] => file
                            [editable] => 1
                            [name] => file.html
                        )
                )
        )
    [empty_folder] => Array
        (
            [fullpath] => /home/public_html/templates/user-defined/empty_folder
            [type] => folder
            [name] => empty_folder
            [files] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [second_folder] => Array
        (
            [fullpath] => /home/public_html/templates/user-defined/second_folder
            [type] => folder
            [name] => second_folder
            [files] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fullpath] => /home/public_html/templates/user-defined/second_folder/alpha_file.html
                            [path] => second_folder/alpha_file.html
                            [type] => file
                            [editable] => 1
                            [name] => alpha_file.html
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [fullpath] => /home/public_html/templates/user-defined/second_folder/bravo_file.html
                            [path] => second_folder/bravo_file.html
                            [type] => file
                            [editable] => 1
                            [name] => bravo_file.html
                        )
                )
        )
    [base_directory] => Array
        (
            [fullpath] => /home/public_html/templates/user-defined/hello_world.html
            [path] => hello_world.html
            [type] => file
            [editable] => 1
            [name] => hello_world.html
        )
)
```

As you can see I have removed the base_directory key and then re-add it at the end so that it will (theoretically) always list the BASE files after the other directories.